# How can I substitute regexp matches and map the substitutions in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I.e.:

```
echo H#97llo | MagicPerlCommand
```

Stdout:

```
Hallo
```

were MagicPerlCommand is something like

```
perl -pnle "s/#(\d+)/chr(\1)/ge"
```

(but that doesn't work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `\1` to `$1` in your MagicPerlCommand.  The `\digit` backreference style doesn't t work when the replacement expression is evaluated (i.e. `s///e`).

That worked for me on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [`j_random_hacker`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47984/jrandomhacker) answer, you must use `$1` rather than `\1`.

This is because using the '`/e`' modifier to the regex means the right hand half is just another normal Perl expression, and not a regex substitution.  Since it's Perl, you've got to use Perl's syntax for the bracket reference, and not the usual regex syntax.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But it's strange that 

echo H#97llo | perl -pnle "s/#(\d+)/chr(\1)/ge" 

actually returned something (and it wasn't an exception).

Comment: on my machines (Linux FC10 and Mac OS X) your code produces a warning "wide character in print".  It's treating the \1 as a reference to a scalar.

Comment: Please note that it produces the same warning in Windows, which makes my delicious comment stupid.